# Font face css only working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, font-face

Hi I know there are many examples of this question but none have yet to offer me a solution. Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'lucida_cal';
 src: url('http://www.mydomain.co.uk/Content/js/lcallig-webfont.eot');
 src: url('http://www.mydomain.co.uk/Content/js/lcallig-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('http://www.mydomain.co.uk/Content/js/lcallig-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('http://www.mydomain.co.uk/Content/js/lcallig-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
        url('http://www.mydomain.co.uk/Content/js/lcallig-webfont.svg#lucida_calligraphyitalic') format('svg');

 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    font-family:lucida_cal, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

I have all versions in the root of where the css file is. I have tried `url('lcallig-webfont.woff')` also. It is working in Chrome but no other browser.

Comment: For h1 font-family, do `font-family:'lucida_cal', Geneva, sans-serif;`

Comment: Where does the font really come from? Please do not use domains like www.domain.co.uk as dummies, they aren’t. If you cannot (why?) reveal the real address, at least use the conventional example.com. The problem is probably in the font.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sorry this is my local domain. the fonts are installed in the root directory of the css file

Comment: @Dom Sorry this did not work

Comment: @CR41G14 hmm, okay, try changing the name of the font-family to: `'lcallig-webfont'`. So it would be: `@font-face {
 font-family: 'lcallig-webfont';}`, then `@h1{font-family:'lcallig-webfont', Geneva, sans-serif;}`

Comment: Where is the font from, and how did you generate the files? “lucida−cal” sounds like Lucida Calligraphy, so did Bigelow and Holmes deliver you font files for web usage?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I had the font from an open source site and run it through font-squirrel. Is there a problem with the font? But it works in chrome

Comment: Yes, probably there is a problem with the font. You still haven’t specified where you got it from.